# Includes is not a Function When Using it on Function Parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to convert times to minute. Whenever "X hours" is input it'd be converted to X hours in minutes. The function I'm using throws an error saying includes isn't a function. I've used includes in the same project so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

```js
function calcTotalCook(prep, rest, cook) {
  //console.log(rest);

  if (prep.includes('hours')) {
    prep = prep.replace('hours', '');
    prep = Number(prep) * 60;
  }

  if (rest.includes('hours')) {
    rest = rest.replace('hours', '');
    rest = Number(rest) * 60;
  }

  if (cook.includes('hours')) {
    cook = cook.replace('hours', '');
    cook = Number(cook) * 60;
    console.log(cook);
  }

  document.getElementById('totalTime').innerText = Number(prep) + Number(rest) + Number(cook);
}
```

```html
<div class="fourth clearfix">
  <h2>Prep Time:</h2>
  <input type="text" id="prepTime" name="prepTime" class="inputField" value="">
</div>
<div class="fourth">
  <h2>Rest Time:</h2>
  <input type="text" id="restTime" name="restTime" class="inputField" value="">
</div>
<div class="fourth">
  <h2>Cook Time:</h2>
  <input type="text" id="cookTime" name="cookTime" class="inputField" value="">
</div>
<div class="fourth">
  <h2>Total Time:</h2>
  <label id="totalTime" name="totalTime"></label>
</div>
<input type="button" class="addButton" value="Calc" onclick="calcTotalCook(document.getElementById('prepTime').value, document.getElementById('restTime').value, document.getElementById('cookTime').value);">
```

Comment: How do you call the function? Note that older browsers do no support `String.prototype.includes` method.

Comment: Forgot my button. It's been added.

Comment: this error occurs (unsurprisingly) when you call a method that's not on the prototype of the callee. However you're passing these variables into that function, they're not strings. are you just passing in the element instead? Console.log the vars beforehand and see what they are.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @epascarello Firefox 62.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code in Firefox and Chrome... all fine. IE11 is of course throwing the error. See [compatibility for includes](https://caniuse.com/#search=includes). If compatibility with IE is a concern, you should use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead of includes.

So instead of `if (prep.includes('hours'))` you would be using `if (prep.indexOf('hours') > -1)`.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 62.0.2. As I mentioned, includes works elsewhere in my project.

Comment: Okay, there must be something else happening then. `.includes` can only be used on a String or an Array. If you use it on a Number, you get `"TypeError: a.includes is not a function"`. Are you absolutely sure `prep`, `rest` and `cook` are all Strings? You can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to verify the data type of each `calcTotalCook` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You code snippet should work fine with modern day browsers except Internet Explorer. Check below image for supported browser.

[image: Browser Support]

Instead you can use `indexOf` method.